# htaccess rewrite rule with param before filename

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I'm not able to get my rewriting rules to work. I've read tutorials but nothing explains clearly how i can use a param before my filename when i'm not calling the root index.  It seems that my index rule overides all the other ones.

I want my index to show galleries according to specific tags, so all kind of links looking this way would go to index.php

```
www.mawebsite.com/en/tag/karate = www.mawebsite.com?lang=en&tag=karate
```

this part is working fine and my gallery load as i wish. But then i want to be able to use other files.

```
www.mawebsite.com/en/video/videoid/video-title = www.mawebsite.com/video.php?lang=en&guid=videoid&title=video-title.
```

Here how my htaccess file looks so far.

EDIT my file:

```
AddCharset UTF-8 .html
ErrorDocument 404 /notfound.html


RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(\w\w)/(video)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /$2.php?lang=$1&guid=$3&title=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^fr/video/guid/title$ video.php [L]
RewriteRule fr/tag/([^/]+/.+)$ /?=$1 [L,QSA]
#RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?p=$1 [L]

Redirect 301 /css/file.css /css/file.php
```

anything i tried going to `video.php` won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the following rules a try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(\w\w)/(video)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /$2.php?lang=$1&guid=$3&title=$4 [L]
```

---

The ordering of rewrite rules plays a very important part. Keep the more specific rules first:

```
AddCharset UTF-8 .html
ErrorDocument 404 /notfound.html

Redirect 301 /css/file.css /css/file.php

RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(\w\w)/(tag)/([^/]+)/?$ /?lang=$1&$2=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(\w\w)/(video)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /$2.php?lang=$1&guid=$3&title=$4 [L]
```

Comment: thanks, but it stays on the index, it seems that my last rule overrides the one you suggest

Comment: @Vakarm Can you put the entire htaccess file in the question?

Comment: @Vakarm Updated my reply above.

Comment: I got it to work another way, now every link goes to an handler.php file that loads video.php if /video/ is in url...